# How can I preserve command line spaces in a linux application?

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments

As per [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099712/whats-the-accepted-method-for-deploying-a-linux-application-that-relies-on-share), I'm deploying a linux application on some local servers using a shell script that looks like:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   exec ./TheBinary $*
```

When I run TheBinary without these wrappers (but after having modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which I want to do via the script post-deployment), I can preserve spaces in the command line arguments using double quotes (").  But the above script appears to sanitize them away; how can I modify this script to respect spaces in command line arguments that are wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: Are you quoting both "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and "$*"?

Comment: trying to quote "$*" leaves the application thinking that it has only one command line argument.

Comment: Oops, got it... See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST for a longer description. @sehe has it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec ./TheBinary "$@"
```

I have no real idea whether /bin/sh supports that syntax