# Error loading SDL2 shared libraries while executing program on another pc

Tags: c++, linux, g++, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile a program i made using SDL2 to work on others computers (or testing VM in this case). 
I've been compiling it with what i think are the correct flags, e.g. `g++ main.cpp -o main -lSDL2`, however when i try executing it on another Ubuntu installation i get this error.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

From my understanding it's not a problem in my compiling but with how i expect it to work on another Linux installation; I've cross-compiled (using mingw32) and tested it (using a freshly installed VM) on Windows adding the correct dlls with the exe (seems to work fine) and I was expecting for it to work in a similar fashion.

What's the standard in this cases? Should i write a setup scripts to install the library dependencies on the target machine? Is there another way I'm not aware of? I've never released an application for Linux (nor Windows) and I'm struggling to find the resources to do things "the right way".

Comment: It means the libSDL is not installed on the other machine or a different version is installed.

Comment: The safe way is to compile statically and avoid all dependencies, *especially* from inter-OS compilations.

Comment: ***Is there another way I'm not aware of?*** There are several ways. The simplest for you is to just list the requirement in your documentation for your application. More difficult involve package managers  / distro support (which distro do you choose to support?) Then there is the problem of availability. A certian version of a library may not exist in all distros and there may be an ABI incompatibility using a different version.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm currently xubuntu 18.04 since it's the one I'm more familiar with. I shouldn't have problem with similar distros like ubuntu and such.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis i've been trying to compile statically with little success so far

Comment: Related (maybe a solution): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099712/whats-the-accepted-method-for-deploying-a-linux-application-that-relies-on-shar?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099712/whats-the-accepted-method-for-deploying-a-linux-application-that-relies-on-shar?rq=1)

Comment: @RiccardoCecconi what have you tried and what was your result? As said before, in some cases saying 'do apt-get install libsdl2' in documentation or building your own package may be fine. Carry your dependencies with you if that's not acceptable. Use `ldd ./your_program` to check its dependencies (note that this is recursive though), there may be more dependencies than you think. SDL2 can be linked statically (if you have static version installed on your machine) but user can still override it with their own version if needed. libc usually can't, for legal reasons.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do the same thing on windows - either require user to install libraries or carry them with you.

Comment: @drescherjim that seems to be addressing my question exactly, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone suggestions, I ended up settling for the easy way, compiling the "easy to install" libraries dynamically e.g.`-lSDL2` and the others statically (checked the licenses and it should be fine) like so:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -Wl,-Bdynamic -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2_gfx -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

I'll put in my documentation how to install the required SDL2 libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how familiar you are with `pkg-config`, but the output for `sdl2` is this:

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2
```

This was found from running this:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2
```

Basically, you need to point to where SDL2 is located **BEFORE** you actually link to it.

The tool `pkg-config` is designed to tell you the information you need when you want to link to a package in Linux. You were linking with the library, but you forgot to tell `GCC` where the library is located.

If you want to compile you code, try this:

```
g++ main.cpp -o runme `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
```

This will automatically grab all of the flags that you need to compile with SDL2 included.

Oh, and you should note, ORDER MATTERS WHEN ADDING FLAGS AND LIBRARIES!!!

There are many questions on SO where the order of compiler options caused all of the problems. Do not be like those people. I suggest you search SO for more info on that.

Comment: The error is a runtime error because the .so file does not exist on the other linux box. Not sure that this answer addresses this.

Comment: But, it cannot **find** the shared library: `No such file or directory`. Which is what I **am** addressing. This error can come up if the library is not being found.
You may be correct in that the solution I provide is not what is needed, but until the OP tries it out, neither of us can know for sure.
The attached link even simply shows how to add a library location to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is just a cleaner way of doing the same thing.
(cleaner could be a matter of opinion though)

Comment: I think you are addressing can not find the `.so` on the build machine however that is not an issue. Does this help not being able to find the `.so` during run time on some linux machine?

Comment: Sorry but no, it's not doing the same thing. `-L` flags are passed to linker (e.g. `ld`), will only affect local build on developer's machine (which OP said is fine), and does not affect runtime linker (e.g. `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`). Only things affecting where runtime linker searches for libraries upon application startup are ldconfig, `LD_LIBRARIES_PATH` and rpath; libraries paths are not saved in ELF and libraries are not required to be on the same path on target machine. So we can know for sure it wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: @thatrobotguy as @drescherjm said the error happens during runtime, my program compiles fine. However it's good to know about `pkg-config`.