# Starting a std::thread with static linking causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11

To learn c++11 (and boost) I am writing a simple http-server using boost asio and c++11 (for threading and lambdas).

I want to test the new c++11 lambdas and std::thread so I tried to start the `io_service.run()` like this in a std::thread with a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class HttpServer
{
public:
    HttpServer(std::size_t thread_pool_size)
    : io_service_(),
    endpoint_(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 8000),
    acceptor_(io_service_, endpoint_)
    { }

    void Start() {
        acceptor_.listen();
        cout << "Adr before " << &io_service_ << endl;
        std::thread io_thread([this](){
            cout << "Adr inside " << &io_service_ << endl;
            io_service_.run();
        });
        io_thread.join();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
    tcp::endpoint endpoint_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main() {
    HttpServer server(2);
    server.Start();
}
```

This terminates with segmentation fault. Additionally sometimes it is running the cout inside the lambda, sometimes not (although endl should flush). In any case, it prints the correct address of `io_service_`. However, when I replace the `std::thread` with a `boost::thread` (no other change!), everything is working fine.

I would appreciate it if anyone has an idea where the problem is caused (could be asio, std::thread or std::lambda).

Additional information:

According to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895879/using-member-variable-in-lambda-capture-list-inside-a-member-function) accessing the member io_service_ within a lambda is fine when capturing `this`, as I do it.

I am running gcc 4.6.1 on Ubuntu and boost 1.46. G++ parameters:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -static -I/home/andre/DEV/boost_1_48_0/include/ -L/home/andre/DEV/boost_1_48_0/lib/ -o webserver main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread
```

**Update:**

Removing -static fixed the problem. I found out that the problem has nothing to do with boost or lambdas and can be reproduced whenever building static and using `std::thread`. For any reason this combination does not work.
I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090623/c0x-thread-static-linking-problem) describes almost the same, however I don't really understand the details and the error message is different.

So I wonder why `std::thread` and static linking don't seem to work together. Is there a reason why static linking is not allowed here? I updated the question title and removed the boost tag.

Comment: I know the code above does nothing at this time. I only left what is relevant for the described problem...

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger to see where the segmentation fault is?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, missed that. The segfault was sometimes in the first line of the lambda (cout << ...) and other times in the second line (io_service_.run();). Finally I found out that it has nothing to do with boost or lambdas, but with static linking and std::thread. Removing -static solved the problem. I found a similar post describing such [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090623/c0x-thread-static-linking-problem).

Comment: @andre.hacker post that comment as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing -static solved the problem. I found out that it has nothing to do with boost or lambdas, but with static linking and `std::thread`, which don't seem to work together for any unknown reason (see also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090623/c0x-thread-static-linking-problem) that might be related).

I guess the question why they don't work together is - though interesting - out of scope for now, and I am glad with the answer, so this can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 19):

Link your app with `-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive`
More here https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590
It works for me.

Comment: its a crying shame that even in gcc 6.2 the result of just linking with `-static -pthread` will result in broken executables (i.e. runtime-errors) and no linker errors or even warnings. And I had to spend several hours debugging only to find the issue is known since gcc 4.7 and was resolved as `RESOLVED INVALID`. Your answer finally pointed me to what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone coming here and wondering, yes this is still necessary in 2020 with GCC 10.