# "Operation not permitted" when linking OpenSSL 1.1.0 on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, linker-errors

I built OpenSSL 1.1.0 on OS X:

```sh
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 \
    no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64
make depend
sudo make install
```

I'm having trouble linking this in my system. It's still showing me an older version.

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel    922496 Jul  8 22:51 openssl
```

The linking error I get is:

```
Operation not permitted
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should state your linker error rather than printing your OpenSSL version. After `sudo make install`, run `sudo ln -s /usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl`. That should put your `openssl` program on-path. If you are compiling and linking, then the headers are located at `/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64/include`, and the libraries are located at `/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64/lib`. Use them in your `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: ***`Operation not permitted`*** - you need to state more about your setup and problem. ["Operation not permitted" linker](http://www.google.com/search?q="Operation+not+permitted"+linker) sems to indicate it has something to do with C++11 and multi-threading. I fail to see what that has to do with OpenSSL. I don't normally ask for one, but you probably need to follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also see [What is the correct link options to use std::thread in GCC under linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8649828) and [C++0x thread static linking problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7090623). I'm guessing your issue and the cited questions have a lot in common.